# Korean transit visa for Uzbekistan citizens

Tags: visas, transit-visas, icn, uzbek-citizens

I am travelling to Japan from Uzbekistan through Incheon airport.

Do I need a Korean transit visa, if I only make transfer at Incheon and do not go outside of the airport?